# What's the real lower limit for (signed) long long?

Tags: c++, g++

Checking the limits of the type long long using

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long>::min();
```

I get -9223372036854775808

However when compiling the following code:

```
int main() {
   long long l;
   l=-9223372036854775808LL;
}
```

I get the warnings:

```
test.cpp:3:7: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned.
test.cpp:3: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90
```

What am I missing?
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Giorgio

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This `9223372036854775808LL` is a positive number. So you need to take

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();
```

into consideration. Negating it immediately afterwards doesn't make the operand of the `-` operator itself negative.

Comment: As for why the min and max values aren't exactly symmetric around zero in your system, you may want to read about [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with std::numeric and boost::numeric;  it gives no warnings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/bounds.hpp>
#include <boost/limits.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  std::cout << "The minimum value for long long:\n";
  std::cout << boost::numeric::bounds<long long>::lowest() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long>::min() << std::endl << std::endl;

  std::cout << "The maximum value for long long:\n";
  std::cout << boost::numeric::bounds<long long>::highest() << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() << std::endl << std::endl;

  std::cout << "The smallest positive value for long long:\n";
  std::cout << boost::numeric::bounds<long long>::smallest() << std::endl << std::endl;


  long long l;
  l = boost::numeric::bounds<long long>::lowest();
  std::cout << l << std::endl;
  l = std::numeric_limits<long long>::min();
  std::cout << l << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my system.

```
   {LLONG_MIN}
          Minimum value of type long long.
          Maximum Acceptable Value: -9223372036854775807

   {LLONG_MAX}
          Maximum value of type long long.
          Minimum Acceptable Value: +9223372036854775807
```

see your `limits.h` file

Also it can be found by:

`min : - 2^(sizeof (long long) - 1) - 1`

`max : + 2^(sizeof (long long) - 1)`